# Embedding image in mail body

Tags: image, drupal-7, smtp, mime-mail

I am using Drupal's Mime Mail module and SMTP module.

I am trying to embed an image in my html mail body using as follows:

```
<img src="/muc/sites/default/files/Applicant2.jpg" />
```

Hello

But mail is not being sent. Error:"Message body empty." However, if I use absolute path like

```
<img src="http://localhost/muc/sites/default/files/Applicant2.jpg" />
```

Hello

Mail is being sent but to my gmail account, but image is not visible. As it becomes a remote content. I have read all readme.txt, done googling etc. but didn't find any resolution.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an absolute path for email images in order for an email client to resolve the resources they point to.

This is not the same for a website, for example, where a browser knows how to resolve relative paths because it has the context of the website's domain/host name.